# How to start selenium webdriver server before python test run from command prompt

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to run selenium based python test in command prompt, but my test is not running. Looks like I need to run selenium server before I run the test. Any suggestion how to start selenium webdriver server before .py test run on command promp?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Check selenium documentation for exactly how to start selenium as it differs in different contexts.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.